# Issue in overriding the Price block

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, product-prices

I was trying to override the price block for custom product type and I tried the below code, which is working fine but in base or some theme does not work.

```
    <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>packet</type>
            <block>packetprice/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>packetprice/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
</reference>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If I have such problem, I firstly check existing such product type in config, create object of the block anywhere and check if template exists.

If everything is allright - you should check the method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::addPriceBlockType (put there some breakpoins or Mage::log()). Also look for any rewrites of this method (Better using xdebug)

As your reference exist inside some handle:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<some_of_your_handles>
...
</some_of_your_handles>
```

check if this handle is using on current page (put something like `<remove name="head" />` inside this handle)

**upd.1**

By default magento render price here:
**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml**

`<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` (You can start your debug from here). Also check in method getPriceHtml if you use correct product_type.

The method where magento set price template is:

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::_getPriceBlockTemplate

    protected function _getPriceBlockTemplate($productTypeId)
    {
        if (isset($this->_priceBlockTypes[$productTypeId])) {
            if ($this->_priceBlockTypes[$productTypeId]['template'] != '') {
                return $this->_priceBlockTypes[$productTypeId]['template'];
            }
        }
        return $this->_priceBlockDefaultTemplate;
    }
```

check which template magento try to render

**upd.2**

If you don't use xdebug, better use **Mage::log($param, false, 'somelog.log', true)**
Inside method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getPriceHtml

put following:

**Mage::log(get_class($this), false, 'somelog.log', true);**

**Mage::log($this->getTemplate(), false, 'somelog.log', true);**

Also don't forget that on your page magento can call this method many times (for regular price, for tier price)

Comment: I have tried with these but its not comes inside the price block template (price.phtml). It goes inside addPriceBlockType method and in xml handles.

Comment: updated... look above.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried with this but still its not coming inside this method.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What do you get and where?

Comment: I have print the product type inside this method also add the die(); but it not comes under. I wanna to change the price template on Product view page, as on the list page its working fine.

Comment: Not sure, that you are notified when I edit message. I put update here